# "Rate It" link for windows phone market place

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, windows-store-apps

I am introducing a link(button) from WP7(c#+xna) game which needs to directly go to GAME RATE screen  where people can rate it. but i am not sure where can i find. Please let me know where i would find it to my game at WP market place.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use [`MarketplaceReviewTask`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh394030%28v=vs.105%29.aspx):

```
MarketplaceReviewTask marketplaceReviewTask = new MarketplaceReviewTask();

marketplaceReviewTask.Show();
```

Comment: This is the right thing to do.  I tried a ReviewBugger for one of my apps (because the users didn't use my review button so often) and now I have more reviews. Check the following link: http://igrali.com/2011/12/24/bug-prompt-users-to-leave-you-reviews-and-rates-on-windows-phone-marketplace/

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/wpdevelop/thread/681b031b-a973-4f67-a820-1a594d6c0817/